# In C,why is definition of a global variable in a separate statement raising warning,but is OK for a local variable?

Tags: c, expression, declaration

In the following code, why does the definition of the global variable "x" show the warning "data definition has no type or storage class" but the same thing works fine for the local variable "y"?All I am doing for each variable is first declare them in one statement and then define them in another statement.What is the difference that it works fine for one but shows warning for the other?

```
    #include<stdio.h>

      int x;
      x=303;

     int main(void)
      {
        int y;
        y=776 ;

        printf("The value of x is %d,and of y is %d",x,y);
      }
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. You cannot have statements at the global scope.

Comment: I am afraid it's compiling fine in CodeBlocks (Windows) and shows the output as desired.But the compilation throws the warning I mentioned.Which compiler are u using?

Comment: "first declare them in one statement and then define them in another statement" -- No, you defining (and declaring) them in one statement and assigning to them in another. So you have your very basics wrong ... time to study the language more.

Comment: "That code doesn't even compile. " -- Did you try it? It's legal C89.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're compiling in C89 mode.

```
  int x;
```

is a tentative definition of `x`.

```
  x=303;
```

is then interpreted as a definiton of the variable `x` with implicit type `int` (`int x = 303;`). Under C99 or later, that code would not compile since the "implicit `int`" rule was abolished and without the "implicit `int`" rule, the second line could only be interpreted as a statement, which is not allowed at file scope.

Compiling with `-std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (and adding a `return 0;` to `main`), gcc warns

```
redef.c:4:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
redef.c:4:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘x’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

Comment: why does it warn "no type or storage class"? That appears to indicate that adding a storage class (and still not an explicit type) would make the warning go?

Comment: I must admit that I don't know the details, C89 is not my strong point. It also warns with `extern x = 303;` (because initialising an `extern` doesn't make much sense), doesn't compile with `static` (because of the previous `extern` declaration). Without the previous line, and with `static x = 303;`, it only gives the `implicit int` warning.

Comment: It should compile if they're both declared static, otherwise the first is a tentative external definition, the second an explicit static definition, so it'd have conflicting declarations.

Comment: @teppic Yes. If the first was `static int x;`, there'd be no problem with the line `static x = 303;` after that.

Comment: "why does it warn "no type or storage class"?" -- Do you see a type or storage class in `x=303;`? I don't. "That appears to indicate that adding a storage class (and still not an explicit type) would make the warning go?" -- It doesn't actually indicate any such thing. The warning says both are missing; adding one could result in a warning saying just one is missing. Would the compiler issue a warning for `static x = 303;`? It might, but it isn't required to.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that these two lines:

```
  int x;
  x = 303;
```

Consist of a declaration statement (`int x;`) and an expression used as a statement (`x = 303;`).  The C programming language only allows for declarations and definitions at the level of global scope and disallows expressions at global scope.  However, both declaration statements and expression statements are legal inside of C functions.

One intuitive way to think about this is the following: when would the code `x = 303;` be executed at global scope?  Imagine that we had this program:

```
int x = 1;

void myFunction() {
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

x = 303;
```

Here, what value of `x` would `myFunction` see?  Would it see the value 1, or would it see the value 303?

On the other hand, if we have

```
void myFunction() {
    int x;
    x = 303;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

It is a bit more clear that we are supposed to execute these statements in order, so `303` would be printed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute code outside of any function/block. `x=303;` is not valid in the position where you wrote it.

In this precise case (global scope), you can only initialize the variable directly with `int x=303`.