# Why does assignment from sizeof alter type of variable being assigned from size_t to int?

Tags: c, sizeof, size-t

This program compiles with no warnings and provides the expected output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int i;
size_t s = sizeof(i);

int main(void){
    printf("%zu \n", s);
}
```

But this program does not compile, and I observe the following warnings and errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int i;
size_t s; 
s = sizeof(i);

int main(void){
    printf("%zu \n", s);
}
```

Warnings and errors:

```
    $ gcc -std=c99 -o sizeof_test sizeof_test.c 
sizeof_test.c:6:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
 s = sizeof(i);
 ^
sizeof_test.c:6:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘s’ [enabled by default]
sizeof_test.c:6:1: error: conflicting types for ‘s’
sizeof_test.c:5:8: note: previous declaration of ‘s’ was here
 size_t s; 
        ^
sizeof_test.c: In function ‘main’:
sizeof_test.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%zu’ expects argument of type ‘size_t’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%zu \n", s);
     ^
```

Here's the `gcc` version info:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My understanding is that, at least with c99 and possibly earlier, `sizeof` has a return type of `size_t`, for example as [stated at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

If so, how can assignment from `sizeof` cause some implicit type cast to `int` when it's not done as a direct initialization of the `size_t` variable? Neither `s` nor the return type of the `sizeof` operator are `int`, so where does the `int` type come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C,why is definition of a global variable in a separate statement raising warning,but is OK for a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734901/in-c-why-is-definition-of-a-global-variable-in-a-separate-statement-raising-warn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can only have variable definitions (with an optional initializer) at global scope.  You can't have a executable statements.

When the compiler sees this at global scope:

```
s = sizeof(i);
```

Since statements can't exist there, it assumes it's a variable declaration.  The errors and warnings you get follow from that:

- Since the declaration doesn't define the type, the type defaults to `int`, you get a warning for both of those.
- Then you get an error for conflicting types because this implicitly defined `int` has the same name as the `size_t` defined on the previous line.
- The warning about the invalid `printf` format specifier also follows because the most recent definition of `s` is `int`.

Comment: Major "d'oh" moment for me. I don't know why I did not recognize this. The example I'm working on is more complicated that my example in the question, but still, I should have recognized it.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is, you can't assign variables outside all functions.

```
size_t s; 
s = sizeof(i);
```

These two lines are interpreted as: a global variable `s` with type `size_t`, and **another** global variable `s` with implicit type `int`(which is invalid in C99), and is initialized with`sizeof(i)`.

If you understand this, you can understand all the error/warning messages. They are either related to the implicit `int` type of `s`, or with the fact that two different types of `s` are defined.